# How to replace every second space, but not first/last with "&nbsp;" in a given string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

let's say I have the following string:

```
string s = "A B  C   D    TESTTEST  BLA BLA      TEST       TEST2"
```

Then I need the following:

```
"A B &nbsp;C &nbsp; D &nbsp;&nbsp; TESTTEST &nbsp;BLA BLA &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; TEST &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; TEST2"
```

So the rules are:
a) replace every second space (**between non space chars**) with `&nbsp;`
b) If the last space is replaced with `&nbsp;`, try to move it backwards (if possible) one step so the next word is not touched by the force space.

Background:

I want to use that to print data from the database to my website. But I want to optimize the forced spaces to use less space. I also want the last forced space not to touch the next word (if possible) so it is easier for some search engines to catch that word.

Will I need to loop through every char in that string and count the occurrence or is there an easier, faster and more fancy way?

**Thank you, both solutions are working perfect.**
So I did a benchmark to figure out which solution to accept:

@Guffa, your solution needs 22 seconds for 1 Million runs
@Timwi, your solution needs 7 seconds for 1 Million runs

I will give you both an upvote, but I will accept Timwi's solution.

Comment: `s = String.Concat("<span style=\"white-space: pre\">", s, "</span>")`

Comment: @hobbs: That would prevent the entire string from wordwrapping.

Comment: Very well, `pre-wrap` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Let’s use a regular expression!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-programming-quote/205#205)

```
var input = "A B  C   D    TESTTEST  BLA BLA      TEST       TEST2";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"  +", m =>
    m.Length == 2 ? " &nbsp;" :
    m.Length % 2 == 1 ? " &nbsp;".Repeat(m.Length / 2) + " " :
    " &nbsp;".Repeat(m.Length / 2 - 1) + "&nbsp; ");
```

This uses a `string.Repeat` extension method I wrote:

```
/// <summary>
/// Concatenates the specified number of repetitions of the current string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">The string to be repeated.</param>
/// <param name="numTimes">The number of times to repeat the string.</param>
/// <returns>A concatenated string containing the original string the specified number of times.</returns>
public static string Repeat(this string input, int numTimes)
{
    if (numTimes == 0) return "";
    if (numTimes == 1) return input;
    if (numTimes == 2) return input + input;
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)
        sb.Append(input);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**By the way, if by “saving space” you are referring to bandwidth / storage space,** you can make this even more compact by using `"\xa0"` instead of `"&nbsp;"`, which is equivalent in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
s = String.Concat(
  Regex.Split(s, "( +)")
  .Select((p, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? p :
    String.Concat(
      Enumerable.Repeat(" &nbsp;", p.Length<3 ? p.Length-1 : p.Length/2-1)
      .ToArray()) +
    (p.Length % 2 == 1 ? " " : "") +
    (p.Length > 2 ? "&nbsp; " : ""))
  .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: Damn annoying downvoters, they never leave a comment. +1 to correct it.

Comment: The downvote wasn't from me either. I will try your solution now.

Answer (score 0):

```
s.Replace("  ", " &nbsp;");
```